# Why does this file keep magically coming back after deletion?

Tags: python, windows, discord.py

I'm trying to delete a file that I temporarily downloaded then sent via Discord.py. the file has been deleted, with no errors, but it somehow keeps coming back. I understand it must be something to do with Discord.py sending the request to discord's API, but I don't know what to do about it. after I've sent the message, how can I prevent the file from being kept open and magically sticking around after deletion?

I've tried several things, including closing it explicitly, implicitly via open, deleting via OS.remove() or unlink(), and manually deleting by just clicking the file and removing it in file explorer. So long as the script is running, the file magically reappears. neither OS.remove nor unlink are giving me any errors, and I've confirmed they are working. Manually removing the file does not permanently delete it either. It will only be able to be deleted after closing the script. I want to only store it temporarily so that it doesn't take up space on my server. Can anyone think of solutions or work arounds?

If it helps, this is all being done in a seperate thread via asyncio:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() 
Thread(target=start_mail_loop, args=[loop]).start()
```

```
def start_mail_loop(loop) -> None:
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(mail_loop(), loop)
```

Here's some of my code that handles the files:

This is meant to just delete the files. It works, as best as I can tell, but obviously not with both os.remove and unlink being run at the same time. I have tried merging this with the segment that sends the message, and doing it seperately as shown.

```
for filename in files:
    os.remove(filename)
    file_to_rem = pathlib.Path(filename)
    file_to_rem.unlink()
```

This sends the message with the file through discord.py.

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        await user.send(file=discord.File(f))
        f.close()
```

this is the code that takes the files from an email via mail.

```
filename = part.get_filename()
    if filename:                    
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            f.close()
        parts.append(f"file: {filename}")
```

somehow after everything is said and done, the file keeps magically appearing back where I deleted it from. There are no errors produced. I have no clue how or why, and I would love some helpful work arounds or solutions from more experienced or insightful people.

Comment: I'm not able to give you a for sure answer, but looking at the snippits you provided, I do have some suggestions that could lead you in the right direction. Firstly, when using `with open(...) as f:` you don't need to call f.close(). Once the code leaves the `with` block, the file pointer will be closed. Secondly, I see that you are leveraging asyncio's `await` operator inside a normal `with` block. Asyncio offers an `async with` feature which utilizes an asynchronous context manager, I am wondering if the normal context manager is getting confused with an async operation.